# Wildcard in filename not working in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, git-bash

I know there are many (MANY!) similar questions in here but I haven't been able to find one that solves my problem. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/* MAIN_CLASS and other declarations here */

numOfDatasets=10

for (( i=1; i <= $numOfDatasets; ++i )) do
    DATASET_FILE="C:\path\to\file\name_"$i"_100.fa" 
    QUERY_FILE="C:\path\to\file\name_${i}_100_p"*".fasta"
    mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="${MAIN_CLASS}" -Dexec.args="${DATASET_FILE} ${QUERY_FILE}"
done
```

But I get the error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\file\name_1_100_p*.fasta (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Some examples of the strings I would like to be assigned to `QUERY_FILE` in different iterations are `name_1_100_p95.fasta`, `name_2_100_p79.fasta`, `name_3_100_p89.fasta` etc.
A command like

```
echo "name_"*"_100_p"*".fasta"
```

directly in the terminal works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an inner `for` loop which iterates through the results of the wildcard search:

```
for QUERY_FILE in "C:\path\to\file\name_${i}_100_p"*".fasta"; do
   /* do stuff with $QUERY_FILE */
done
```

Comment: quoting a glob makes it a literal string, not an expansion

Comment: @DTSCode Thanks, I edited my answer. Though it works for me either way.

Comment: I don't see how. `abcd*` is not nearly the same as `"abcd*"`. The for loop would only run once, and have the literal value `C:\path\to\file\name_$i_100_p*.fasta` (except with `i` expanded of course)

Comment: I tested it with `echo $F` inside the for loop and it printed out all of my sample files. But I've just tested it more and indeed there's one iteration so `*` is expanded at `echo`. This means that my first test was wrong, you are right, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `QUERY_FILE` a string value but I think you want it to be the result of running a command instead.
Try something like this:

```
QUERY_FILE=`ls "C:\path\to\file\name_${i}_100_p"*".fasta" | head -1`
```

the `head -1` is if you want the first file matched from the `*`, you can modify that to suit your specific needs.

Full example:

```
#!/bin/bash

/* MAIN_CLASS and other declarations here */

numOfDatasets=10

for (( i=1; i <= $numOfDatasets; ++i )) do
    DATASET_FILE="C:\path\to\file\name_"$i"_100.fa" 
    QUERY_FILE=`ls "C:\path\to\file\name_${i}_100_p"*".fasta" | head -1`  
    mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="${MAIN_CLASS}" -Dexec.args="${DATASET_FILE} ${QUERY_FILE}"
done
```

Comment: No that's not it. If I use `*.fasta` it shows all the files (with both my way and yours). It only doesn't recognize '*' as part of the path.

Comment: You said, "The string I would like to be assigned to `QUERY_FILE` is `name_1_100_p95.fasta`".

So why not just assign it then? `QUERY_FILE="C:\path\to\file\name_${i}_100_p95.fasta"`.  Why are you using a `*`, what are you trying to do with that wildcard?

Comment: You're right, I meant to give an example. It could be `name_2_100_p79.fasta`, `name_3_100_p89.fasta` etc. I'll edit accordingly.